# VBA String.Split Remove Empty Entries

Tags: c#, string, vba, parsing, split

In C#, you can do something like this:

```
string s = "1--2--3";
s.Split(new char[] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and instead of getting {1, ,2, ,3}, you'd get {1,2,3}

I'm trying to do the same in VBA, but I don't see a StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in in VBA. You'll have to roll your own or use some third-party code ([example](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Split.aspx)).

Comment: Use VBA's `Split` function to read `-` seperated entries in an array. Loop through the array and remove empty items.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA there's no simple way, but remove each one.

```
Public Function SplitRemoveEmptyEntries(strInput As String, strDelimiter As String) As String()
Dim strTmp As Variant
Dim sSplit() As String
Dim sSplitOut() As String
ReDim Preserve sSplitOut(0)
  For Each strTmp In Split(strInput, strDelimiter)
    If Trim(strTmp) <> "" Then
      ReDim Preserve sSplitOut(UBound(sSplitOut) + 1)
      sSplitOut(UBound(sSplitOut) - 1) = strTmp
    End If
  Next strTmp
  ReDim Preserve sSplitOut(UBound(sSplitOut) - 1)
  SplitRemoveEmptyEntries = sSplitOut
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A hardcoded example using your specific example - won't work with triple entries

```
Dim arrSplit as Variant
Dim strExample as String
Dim i as Integer

strExample = "1--2--3"

arrSplit = Split(Replace(strExample,"--","),"-") ' Replace double delimiters
for i = lBound(arrSplit) to uBound(arrSplit)
    Debug.Print arrSplit(i)
next
```